# Flutter Web - Seeing weird horizontal scrolling bar after running with --web-renderer html

Tags: html, flutter, web

In order to get images to assets from other websites (ie Firebase storage) to load, I have to run using `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`. Everything works great and looks the same, except for this occasional random horizontal scrolling bar that's hard to explain. There's nothing actually to scroll, even though it shows up (see below). Has anyone seen this and know how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Could u find any solution? I'm having the same problem :(